# How to hide the labels inside swift cocoa pods pie chart

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

have a problem, I tried to disable the showing of labels inside swift pie chart with different methods from stack overflow and etc., but they all want affect.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyf5Z.jpg.
I tried with this code, but it is not working

```
func updateChart(){
        let chartSet = PieChartDataSet(entries: array, label: "")
        let chartData = PieChartData(dataSet: chartSet)
        chartSet.selectionShift = 10
        chart.transparentCircleColor = UIColor.clear
        chart.data?.setValueTextColor(UIColor.clear)
        chart.holeRadiusPercent = 0.65
        chart.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = 0
        chart.legend.enabled = false
        chart.chartDescription?.enabled = false
        chart.minOffset = 0
        chart.centerAttributedText = centerText
        chart.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false //Here id what i tried

        let colors = [UIColor(named:"ChartColor-1"),UIColor(named:"ChartColor-2")]

        chartSet.colors = colors as! [NSUIColor]

        chart.data = chartData


    }
```

Comment: try `chart.drawLabelsEnabled = false`

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Tip for the future: Try to explain your question thoroughly - for example, explaining that you are using the 'Charts' framework with Cocoapods specifically would be helpful to people reading your question. I only knew what you were talking about because I have used that Cocoapod before.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that uses the Charts framework and displays a 'plain' pie chart (one with no text labels at all). I reckon what you need is probably either `data.drawValuesEnabled = false` or `data.drawIconsEnabled = false` in your `PieChartDataSet`, but try the other options listed below if neither of those work.

```
@IBOutlet private weak var chartView: PieChartView! {
    didSet {
        chartView.delegate = self
        chartView.highlightPerTapEnabled = true
        chartView.noDataText = .empty
        chartView.legend.enabled = false
        chartView.rotationEnabled = false
        chartView.centerAttributedText = nil
        chartView.drawCenterTextEnabled = false
        chartView.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = Constants.chartViewTransparentCircleRadiusFraction
        chartView.holeRadiusPercent = Constants.chartViewHoleRadiusFraction
        chartView.transparentCircleColor = Colors.chartViewTransparentCircleColor
        chartView.drawHoleEnabled = true
    }
}

private lazy var dataSet: PieChartDataSet = {
    let data = PieChartDataSet()
    data.label = nil                                            // legend text that appears below the chart
    data.form = .none                                           // legend icon style
    data.drawValuesEnabled = false                              // draw numerical values above each data point
    data.drawIconsEnabled = false                               // draw y-icons on chart
    data.sliceSpace = Constants.chartViewSliceSpace             // size (in pixels) of gap between slices
    data.selectionShift = Constants.chartViewSelectionShift     // increase in size of selected segement (points)
    data.automaticallyDisableSliceSpacing = false               // disables spacing for very narrow slices
    data.entryLabelFont = nil                                   // font for slice label text
    data.colors = [Colors.defaultColor]                         // color of segments (used for all segments if only one value is supplied)
    data.values = []                                            // data points
    return data
}()
```